ListView builder with data from API
i have data from API that contains 400++K data, when I search some data, it works but only shows the data that is on page 1this API contain 10 data per page
this is my controller, i want to search data based on noCtplan and partNo
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../../../data/repositories/wi_repository.dart';
import '../models/kode_proyek.dart';
import '../models/wi.dart';
import 'kode_proyek_controller.dart';

class WiController extends GetxController {
  final WiRepository _wiRepository = WiRepository();
  final KodeProyekController _kodeProyekController =
      Get.put(KodeProyekController());

  var allWi = <Wi>[].obs;
  var proyekDetails = <String, KodeProyek>{}.obs;
  var isLoading = false.obs;
  var filteredWi = <Wi>[].obs;
  var currentPage = 1.obs;
  var totalPages = 1.obs;
  TextEditingController searchTextController = TextEditingController();
  Timer? _debounce;

  Future<void> getWi({int page = 1}) async {
    try {
      isLoading.value = true;
      var response = await _wiRepository.fetchWi(page: page);
      var wiData = response['items'] as List<Wi>;
      var totalPageCount = response['totalPages'];

      if (page == 1) {
        allWi.assignAll(wiData);
      } else {
        allWi.addAll(wiData);
      }

      await _kodeProyekController.fetchAndMatchProyekDetails(wiData);
      _kodeProyekController.proyekDetails.forEach((key, value) {
        if (key != null) {
          proyekDetails[key] = value;
        }
      });
      filteredWi.assignAll(allWi);

      totalPages.value = totalPageCount;
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) print(e.toString());
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }

  void loadMoreWi() async {
    if (currentPage.value < totalPages.value) {
      currentPage.value++;
      await getWi(page: currentPage.value);
    }
  }

  void filterWi(String query) {
    if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce?.cancel();
    _debounce = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
      if (query.isEmpty) {
        filteredWi.assignAll(allWi);
      } else {
        var filtered = allWi.where((wi) {
          var partNo = wi.partNo?.toLowerCase() ?? '';
          var noCtplan = wi.noCtplan?.toLowerCase() ?? '';
          return partNo.contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
              noCtplan.contains(query.toLowerCase());
        }).toList();
        filteredWi.assignAll(filtered);
      }
    });
  }

  void clearSearch() {
    searchTextController.clear();
    filteredWi.assignAll(allWi);
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getWi();
  }
}

repository
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../../features/wi/models/wi.dart';
import '../../utils/http/http_client.dart';

class WiRepository extends GetConnect {
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchWi({int page = 1}) async {
    var url = 'wi-data.php?page=$page';
    final response = await WHttpHelper.get(url);

    final data = {
      'currentPage': response['currentPage'],
      'totalPages': response['totalPages'],
      'items': (response['items'] as List).map((e) => Wi.fromJson(e)).toList(),
    };
    return data;
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> searchWi(String query) async {
    var url = 'wi-data.php?search=$query';
    final response = await WHttpHelper.get(url);

    final data = {
      'currentPage': response['currentPage'],
      'totalPages': response['totalPages'],
      'items': (response['items'] as List).map((e) => Wi.fromJson(e)).toList(),
    };
    return data;
  }
}

and this is my screen page
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../../../../common/styles/spacing_styles.dart';
import '../../../../common/widgets/shadow_search_form.dart';
import '../../../../utils/constants/colors.dart';
import '../../../../utils/constants/sizes.dart';
import '../../../../utils/devices/device_utility.dart';
import '../../controllers/wi_controller.dart';
import 'search.wi_widget/ticket_widget.dart';

class SearchWi extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchWi({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final WiController state = Get.put(WiController());
    final TextEditingController searchTextController = state.searchTextController;

    final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels == scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        state.loadMoreWi();
      }
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: WColors.light,
        title: ShadowSearchForm(
          onSearch: (value) {
            state.filterWi(value);
          },
          controller: searchTextController,
          focusColor: WColors.primary,
          hasBoxShadow: false,
          readOnly: false,
          height: 40,
          showCursor: true,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: WColors.light,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          WDeviceUtils.hideKeyboard(context);
        },
        child: Obx(() {
          if (state.isLoading.value && state.allWi.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: WColors.secondary,
              ),
            );
          }

          // Log data untuk debugging
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print('Displaying data: ${state.filteredWi}');
          }

          return ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController,
            itemCount: state.filteredWi.length + (state.currentPage.value < state.totalPages.value ? 1 : 0),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (index < state.filteredWi.length) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: WSpacingStyle.ticketPadding,
                  child: TicketWidget(index: index),
                );
              } else {
                return const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(WSizes.defaultSpace),
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: WColors.secondary,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

the problem is, can't load data in another page
only show loading, i've waited 1 hour to make sure

Try with this package: ts_paginated_list
